# How should I put resistors in a NOT gate created with a NPN and PNP transistor?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis

I am new to electrical engineering and experimenting with a NOT gate composed of a NPN and PNP transistor using Ngspice.

In the following schematic, the left circuit does not work but the right circuit works well, at least in a simulation.
[image]

The *Vcc* is 5V and the input signal is a periodic square wave. The following is the plot of a transient simulation result for the right circuit.(*I<sub>in,1</sub>*, *I<sub>in,2</sub>*, and *I<sub>out</sub>* are the currents through *R2*, *R3*, and *R1* respectively.)
[image]

I have three questions.

1. Why does not the left one work?
2. Varying the resistance of *R1* does not change the simulation result significantly, even for 0Ω. Then is it possible to remove *R1* in the real circuit? I am scared I will break transistors by letting too much current flow.
3. Why are the voltages at *out1* and *out2* almost the same?

As an extra information, the following is the plot of a transient simulation result for the left circuit.(*I<sub>in</sub>*, *I<sub>out</sub>*, *I<sub>base,1</sub>*, and *I<sub>base,2</sub>* are the currents through *R2*, *R1*, and the base of *Q1*, the base of *Q2* respectively.)
[image]

Comment: I guess in the left one, current flows from VCC, through the emitter, the base, the other base, the other emitter, and into GND and there is nothing to stop it. This turns both transistors on. On the right, the input either stops the PNP base current if it's high or stops the NPN base current if it's low.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In your left circuit Q1 will immediately pass a high current from emitter to base (pin 3 to pin 2), that current will turn on Q2 and it will just remain on. The "In" signal coming through R2 cannot over power that high current so it will have no effect. You need the extra resistors on each base pin (as in the right circuit) so that both transistor inputs are isolated and controlled only by the "In" signal.
2. R1 prevents a high current from flowing between Q1 and Q2 during the switching transitions.  During a transitions there will be some short time when both transistors can be on.
3. After switching the voltage at out1 and out2 will be nearly the same because one transistor will be on and the other will be off, (there will be almost no current flowing in R1 so there is no voltage difference).

Answer (score 2):

1. Transistors would burn up with that circuit on the left. VBE of transistors can be simplified to be 0.7V, so your top transistor allows only 4.3V or more on base, while bottom transistor only allows 0.7V or less on base. Those are contradictory requirements and there is nothing to limit base current when you shorted them together. Even in an ideal simulator, huge current would flow between bases at low impedance.
2. No the resistor can't be 0R or removed from the same reason you can't directly connect bases together in the first case. The base resistor needs to be just enough so a reasonable (say 1mA) base current flows when transistor is on, and almos no current flows when on.
3. Base resistor of 10k is quite large, so transistor can't pass much collector current, and basically one of the transistors is always almost off so very little current flows in the 1k resistor, therefore there is not much voltage difference over the resistor.

Answer (score 1):

> the left circuit does not work

Learning basics of electronics from the rather interaction-unfriendly variants of Spice is a surefire way to miss the forest for the trees. I don't think I'd learn much had I started out that way. It's not impossible, but for sure not an easy way to learn - especially with no guidance from someone experienced.

Interactive breadboarding is IMHO absolutely necessary to develop intuition, watching the output on the oscilloscope and watching the supply current. Turning the supply voltage up slowly from 0V, you'd see that it actually does work if you don't overload the transistors. And **you would feel them getting hot** - that's why good Spice packages like MicroCap can display dissipation and other "operating region" information about the components (such as a transistor being in cutoff/linear mode/saturated).

Had you used MicroCap - which I'd recommend if you want to use Spice - there would be nice HOT annotations on the transistors as soon as any analysis was performed. In most cases, when you're not exploring power electronics, this indicates some mistake in the design and would give you a non-functional circuit.

VCC must be below two diode drops so that the B-E diodes don't permanently conduct, otherwise the power supply current limit will kick in or the transistors will protect the rest of the circuit by evaporating relevant parts of their dies.

The 1st circuit has two base-emitter diodes in series, as shown on the right below.

At around 0.9V-1.2V, the circuit does work. It can be much, much faster than what's shown, but the behavior gets rather complex, and a square wave input gives let's say an optimistic view of what's going on.

See the [series of excellent log posts by Ted Yapo](https://hackaday.io/project/19333-cbjt-logic) for further reference. There's also a related post by Yann Guidon [Low-Voltage, Complementary Bipolar Logic](https://hackaday.io/project/19304-ygrec-si/log/51655-low-voltage-complementary-bipolar-logic).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwdRBC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The base resistor needs to either be much smaller than 10kΩ to get reasonable speeds, or it needs a parallel speed-up capacitor.

Plotted below are the TOP and BOTTOM signals against the INPUT. It "works" with caveats explored in the blog posts mentioned above. The overshoot on the input edges occurs in a breadboarded version as well.

[image: Output signal waveforms vs. the input waveform]